# Reify triples in JSON-LD

Tags: rdf, json-ld

Suppose I have the following JSON doc:

```
{
  "@id":"http://www.example.com/id/linkFrom",
  "http://www.example.com/link":{
    "@id":"http://www.example.com/id/linkTo",
    "linkType":{
      "@id": "http://www.example.com/vocab#specialLink"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I express that the triple `<http://www.example.com/id/linkFrom> <http://www.example.com/link> <http://www.example.com/id/linkTo>` has the type `http://www.example.com/vocab#specialLink`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really want to assign "a type" to the whole triple, but as you ask for it and mention [Reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29#Reification_on_Semantic_Web), you could do something like this:

```
[
  {
    "@id": "http://www.example.com/id/linkFrom",
    "http://www.example.com/link": [
      {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/id/linkTo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@id": "http://www.example.com/reifi/1",
    "@type": [
      "http://www.example.com/vocab#specialLink",
      "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Statement"
    ],
    "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#subject": [
      {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/id/linkFrom"
      }
    ],
    "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#predicate": [
      {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/link"
      }
    ],
    "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#object": [
      {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/id/linkTo"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```